# Android CountUp timer in a separated class

Tags: android, timer

First of all , I'm totally new in android and java. I'm making a simple android app and it has about 10 activities. What I want is to make a separated class contains a timer and it starts when the app starts first activity, and I need to put a textview to show the value of the timer in all activities. Just show the value of the timer that already running in the separated class, so at the end of the activity No.10 the text view will show the total time that the user spent in all activities. if there is a full example that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Building Counter Fragment***

start your idea by implementing [fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) lets call it `CountUpFragment` and `fragmentActivity` which will be the base of your app where you will add `CountUpFragment` to the activity.

***Why Fragments***

you also want to keep space for other fragments to add to the layout.
keep in mind you are gonna need to use fragments or you're gonna need to create new one each time you're navigating through your app, which will defeat the purpose of fragments reusability.

```
 <LinearLayout ....
    <fragment  android:id="@+id/countup_fragment" ... />
    <!-- here you may want to have other displaying fragments  -->
    <fragment .../>
  </LinearLayout>
```

***CountUpFragment***

Now `CountUpFragment` will have it's own layout such as `TextView` to display the counter time.

***Counting***

[CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way. ( there is example in the link)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider fragments instead of Activities. You would have one Activity, which can have the `TextView` placed on screen, and transition the fragments as the user moves through the app. Fragments are a bit of an advanced topic for new developers though, so I would spend a lot of time reading about the Activity lifecycle, the Fragment lifecycle, and how to work with fragments dynamically. Some links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

```
_countTimer = new CountDownTimer(40000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String _millis=String.valueOf(40-(millisUntilFinished/1000));
            CameraScreen._timerTxt.setText("0."+_millis);
        }
_countTimer.start();
```

Comment: what will be the value of `millisInFuture` and `countDownInterval` to delay for 2 seconds from 0 - 2 seconds not 2 - 0, means count up not count down. what will be value should put in the `setProgress(float progress)`?